# how to delete file

Tags: c#

Hi I have winform which I use it to display image (which I load to picture box , I create this picture box in runtime)

When I select any of this image and delete it (I want to delete it from the folder) but the problem when I delete by :
  File.Delete(path_OF_Image);

the C# give me message which can't delete this file because there is process use this file.

but I dispose all picture box or container (have all my picture box)

but the problem still be.

Comment: There's a tickbox below rating (to the left) on each answer to your question. Just tick the one you think is the most helpful/answers your question.

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing that you are loading the image using the filename directly (i.e. Image.FromFile); this can be problematic due to .NET hanging onto to resources used by the GDI+ library therefore I would recommend loading the file bytes in first, and then initialise the image that way. For example:

```
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
Image image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
   image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before, delete the image try to set empty the PictureBox and then Delete, or make one tmp, just to see the image before to the delete action.

See You

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is: the file is still open, must be first close it before delete it.